# how to set idle session in php when page is idle

Tags: php

**login.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
if($_POST['submit1'])
{
  $v1 = "FirstUser";
  $v2 = "MyPassword";
  $v3 = $_POST['text1'];
  $v4 = $_POST['pwd'];
  if($v1 == $v3 && $v2 == $v4)
  {
    $_SESSION['luser'] = $v1;
    //-----------------------------------------------

    $_SESSION['start'] = time(); // taking now logged in time
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60) ; // ending a session in 30     minutes from the starting time
    header("location: http://127.0.0.1/session_exmpl/home.php");

    //-----------------------------------------------
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Please enter Username or Passwod again !";
  }

}
?>
<html>
<form name="form1" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Username </td><td><input type="text" name="text1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SignIn" name="submit1"> </td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</html>
```

**home.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['luser']))
{
  echo "Please Login again";
  echo "<a href='http://localhost/somefolder/login.php'>Click Here to Login</a>";

}
else
{

  $now = time(); // checking the time now when home page starts

  if($now > $_SESSION['expire'])
  {
    echo $now;
    ?> <br>
    <?
    echo $_SESSION['expire'];
    session_destroy();
    echo "Your session has expire ! <a href='http://127.0.0.1/session_exmpl/login.php'>Login Here</a>";
  }
  else
  { //starting this else one [else1]

    ?>


    <!-- From here all HTML Coding can be done -->


    <html>
    <br />
    <?
    echo $_SESSION['start'];
    ?>
    <br />
    <?
    echo $_SESSION['expire'];
    ?>
    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['luser'];

    ?>
    </html>

  <?php
  }
}
?>


here there are two file login.php and home.php when user successfully logedin the session start with that logedin time and session timed out after 5 minutes.
```

It counting time from the login time but now i want to change this session with idle session timeout.
It should be destroyed when the user do not perform any action with home page the session should be destroyed which changes i need for this.thanks in advanced....

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is rendered, PHP is done. You need a client-side language to do this.

Probably the most reasonable way is to use PHP to export the expire value into a JavaScript variable, and then set an interval listener which will check if the expiry time is less than now, and if so, alert the user.

If you still want to use PHP for this (to destroy the session, communicate with the database, etc.), the only way is to make an AJAX call and you'd still do it from JavaScript. In layman's terms, PHP falls asleep as soon as it renders the page, and you can use an AJAX call to wake it up.

Since you didn't show any attempt to solve this, I'm not going to give you any code. But, what I wrote above is more than enough to get you started.